# Import an HTML table using XSL

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I have constructed an XSL file that parses an XML formatted log and generates an HTML page with information from the log. In this same XSL file, I am attempting to use XSL to pull in an external HTML file that contains a table that I want to display. As it stands, I can display the entire page that contains the table, but am unable to isolate the table. How can this be done? Currently, I can pull in the entire page using the following code:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document($tablePageUrl)" />
```

However, I don't understand how to traverse the HTML body and pull out a copy of the table. An example of how the HTML document is formatted (the document is proper XML, but not proper HTML):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    Table Contents
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to select a particular element in the document.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document($tablePageUrl)/html/body/table" />
```

Comment: I had tried using XPath but was using incorrect syntax. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: No problem. Understanding XPath is essential to using XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

**From comments:**

> I had tried using XPath but was using
>   incorrect syntax

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets

> The `/` and `//` operators compose an
>   expression and a relative location
>   path. It is an error if the expression
>   does not evaluate to a node-set. The
>   `/` operator does composition in the
>   same way as when `/` is used in a
>   location path

In particular, this syntax:

```
document($tablePageUrl)/html/body/table
```

Following the production:

```
PathExpr    ::=   FilterExpr '/' RelativeLocationPath 

FilterExpr  ::=   PrimaryExpr 

PrimaryExpr ::=   FunctionCall
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether the HTML is in a namespace. (Look for a telltale xmlns="....".) Your sample isn't in a namespace, but from experience, if people don't realise that namespaces matter, they often remove the namespace declaration when posting samples. If the elements are in a namespace, then the XPath expression needs to use prefixed names to select them.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:variable name="source-html" select="document('url')" />

<xsl:value-of select="$source-html//table" />
```

Comment: I am still unable to pull in the table using this method. However, when I use:

    <xsl:copy-of select="$source-html" />

The entire HTML document is imported properly. I cannot find a way to reference anything besides the entire document.

Comment: 1) is your html well-formed xml? 2) what do you get when you use <xsl:copy-of select="$source-html//table" />?

Comment: I don't think you can use // from the root node, doesn't it need to be one level in?

Comment: you can use // in any of your xpath expressions.